# class definition error in python

Tags: python, class, constructor

What is wrong with defining a class constructor like this:

I am trying to construct two different objects based on whether input d stays None or gets value assigned.

```
class MSMeshFace(object):

    def __init__(self, a= None, b= None, c= None, d= None):
            self.a = a
            self.b = b
            self.c = c
            self.d = d
            if self.d == None:
                    triangleFace = MSMeshFace(self.a, self.b, self.c)
                    self.count = 3
                    return triangleFace
            else:
                    quadFace = MSMeshFace(self.a, self.b, self.c, self.d)
                    self.count = 4
                    return quadFace
```

Comment: You can't `return` values from an init function. Well, you can, but the result gets thrown away.

Comment: Also, this probably results in an infinite-loop of constructors. _Why_ are you doing this? What's your goal?

Comment: This definition is recursive.

Comment: Do you actually *want* *"two different objects"*, or are you just looking for a way to set `count` based on whether or not `d` is supplied?

Comment: I wanted a way to construct that object from either inputs abc, or abcd. so when I call MSMeshFace(a,b,c) i get a triangleFace and when i call MSMeshFace(a,b,c,d) i get a quadFace

Comment: also i want to set count based on whether d is supplied. but i see how to do it now...Bruno below has an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to return an object of different types based on arguments, make a new function like:

```
def make_face(*args):
    if len(args) == 3:  # triangle face
        return TriMeshFace(*args)
    else:  # quad face
        return QuadMeshFace(*args)
```

You can't (normally) change type in a constructor (you may be able to in `__new__`, though, but you don't need that for this). If you want to add functions to `MSMeshface` (as you suggest in the comments), define a base class containing those functions such as:

```
class MeshBase:
    def addData(self, data): pass
    def ToDSMeshFace(self): pass

class TriMeshFace(MeshBase): pass

class QuadMeshFace(MeshBase): pass
```

Comment: how can i do that inside of a class instead of a function? like i want ability to call MSMeshFace(a,b,c) and get TriMeshFace back but also if i call MSMeshface(a,b,c,d) and get QuadMeshFace

Comment: Just call your function `MSMeshface`? Why does it have to be inside the class?

Comment: i would like to have class functionality so that i can add more functions to it ex. MSMeshFace(a,b,c).addData() or MSMeshFace(a,b,c).toDSMeshFace()

Answer (score 2):

The constructor (well, the initializer, really) is not supposed to return anything, it's supposed to initialize a newly created instance. What you want is:

```
class MSMeshFace(object):
    def __init__(self, a=None, b=None, c=None, d=None):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        self.d = d
        self.count = 3 if self.d is None else 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Your intention seems to be as follows:

```
class MSMeshFace(object):
    def __init__(self, a= None, b= None, c= None, d= None):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        self.d = d
        self.count = 3 if self.d is None else 4
```

The constructed object will be returned automatically. The object already exists, and is pointed by `self`. You can't influence the moment of creation of the object in the class's `__init__` method, you can only *initialize* it.